# Weird converting output from NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have weird result trying to output `NSDate` object from `NSString`.
My `NSString` is: 1976-06-11
My method to convert is:

```
-(NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
}
```

But it output `1976-06-10 21:00:00 +0000`

How could that happen? Difference in 1 day.

Comment: what is your dateString provided for such an output?

Comment: time zone issue. Try giving timezone to NSDateFormatter

Comment: Difference is 3 hours, not a day. Your time zone is UTC+3 isn't it? `NSLog` prints dates always in UTC, the date is correct.

Comment: @vadian yes it is +3. How to fix that issue?

Comment: Set timezone of datefomatter `[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];`

Comment: @NiravD what is - GMT-07:00?

Comment: There is nothing to fix unless you explicitly need the date in UTC. In this case set the time zone of the date formatter accordingly.

Comment: @vadian difference in 1 day, and that actually a birthdate, how you imagine that mistake like this is acceptable?

Comment: Once again, it's not a mistake, the date is correct. `1976-06-10 21:00:00 +0000` and `1976-06-11 00:00:00 +0300` are the same.

Comment: @vadian yes, okay, its correct, but what date it will output on a screen?

Comment: It depends on the kind of the output. I proposed a solution in my previous comment.

Comment: @vadian ok, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following methods to convert an UTC date string into UTC date and local date

```
 - (NSDate *)convertIntoGMTZoneDate:(NSString *)dateString
    {
        NSDateFormatter *gmtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [gmtFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        [gmtFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        [gmtFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

        return [gmtFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    }

    - (NSDate *)convertIntoSystemZoneDate:(NSString *)dateString
    {
        NSDateFormatter *systemZoneFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [systemZoneFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        [systemZoneFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        [systemZoneFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

        return [systemZoneFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have date in UTC format. Use this code to converting your date to local time:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds; // assume this exists
NSDate *ts_utc = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];

NSDateFormatter *utcFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
utcFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
utcFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz";

NSDateFormatter *localFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
localFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
localFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz";

NSString *utcDateString = [utcFormatter stringFromDate:ts_utc];
NSString *LocalDateString = [localFormatter stringFromDate:ts_utc];
```

Or you can use `[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]` to prevent hardcoded strings for timezone names. This method returns the system time zone, If no default time zone has been set.

Answer (score 1):

```
func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> NSDate {
    // Convert string to date object
    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormat.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    var date = dateFormat.dateFromString(dateString)!
    print(date)
    return date
}
```

output : 
1976-06-11 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: use this instead 
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

Answer (score 1):

If you debug code, it shows 1 day difference but after run you will find the actual date which is you enter.

It works for me.I think it will helps you.
Thank you